# nine images in 3 by 3 in android layout

Tags: android, layout

For an intro page, for an Android app, I want to make 9 buttons in this order:

```
[img1][img2][img3]
[img4][img5][img6]
[img7][img8][img9]
```

There is a whitespace between every image(10dp)

The problem, when I'm using LinearLayouts, there always is a white space. Same for a table. 
I cannot use a GridLayout because the app needs to support Android 2.2

I hope you could help me!

P.S.
Here is an example of the code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tl"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_tl" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_tc" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_tr" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_ml" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_mc" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_mr" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_bl" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_bc" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="220dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home_br" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the images not fit in the screen. It must be suitable for every size (even for tablets 10.1)

Solved:
I added for every imageview `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and used  `layout_weight="1"`

Comment: I'm not clear. You want to get rid of the white spaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and inside that,take 3 ImageButtons and keep the width of each as fill_parent and weight = 1,this will give equal width to all the 3  imageButton.

for eg

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientaion="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

   <LinearLayout
   android:orientaion="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
  android:orientaion="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
      <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
      <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
      <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
     android:orientaion="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
      <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
      <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
      <ImageButton
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
  </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is what i tried at first, but there will be a problem with the hight of the imageview. I uploaded an image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/713/naamloosmp.png/
`<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/home_tl" />`

Comment: don't go for android:layout_width="wrap_content"..instead go for android:layout_width="fill_parent" whenever you are using weight=1..And for height you have the attributes like minHeight and maxHeight...You can use that to predefine what should be your min height and max height when the devices are different..

Comment: I've gote the solution. Thanks to you and Diamond. Thanks!

Comment: Please then post the solution So that it may be useful for someone like you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add this to the `ImageView`:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: I've gote the solution. Thanks to you and Androider. Thanks!